# Any replacement for Path.GetFullPath in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In the .NET API for Windows Store Apps the Path class does not have the GetFullPath method. I need to normalize a path though, which was easy using GetFullPath. Does anyone know another method or external code that normalizes a path? What I mean with that is for example:

- add the application's path if the path does not start with a drive
- handle ..\ and .\ correctly

GetFullPath is pretty complex and mimicking the functionality is not easy.

Comment: Chicken and egg question.  The concept of a default working directory for a process is entirely gone in WinRT.  So you never have a need for translating relative paths either.

Comment: Can I know the reason you need the full path? All file references in WinRT, as far as I know, are done in relative path. If you need an absolute path you are normally looking at a URI, in which it has a new constructor that takes in a BaseUri + your relative path to get you the fully qualified path.

Comment: The reason for my question was that I am writing the new edition of my C# Codebook. I try to translate all recipes (code snippets) of the book to the .NET API for Windows Store Apps. Even if I am unsure if a recipe is useful or not, it may be useful for someone who reads the book. I agree that full paths do not make real sense in regular Windows Store Appps. But they could make sense for example when using StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync and StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync if the capabilities PrivateNetworkClientServer and EnterpriseAuthentication or HomeGroup are declared.

Comment: I just tried accessing folders and files using StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync and passing a full UNC path or a full path to a file on a removable storage device. It works if the capabilities "PrivateNetworkClientServer" respectively "Removable storage" are declared. UNC paths then even work with local files! Hence it makes perfect sense to work with full paths, at least in company environments (where an app ist installed directly, skipping the Store and the certification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find any replacement for GetFullPath, but developed a method that handles parent directory tokens (..\) like GetFullPath.

Here it is:

```
public static string NormalizePath(string path)
{
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) == false)
   {
      // Correct multiple backslashes
      path = Regex.Replace(path, @"\\+", @"\");

      // Correct parent directory tokens with too many points in it
      path = Regex.Replace(path, @"\\\.\.+", @"\..");

      // Split the path into tokens
      List<string> resultingPathTokens = new List<string>();
      var pathTokens = path.Split('\\');

      // Iterate through the tokens to process parent directory tokens
      foreach (var pathToken in pathTokens)
      {
         if (pathToken == "..")
         {
            if (resultingPathTokens.Count > 1)
            {
               resultingPathTokens.RemoveAt(resultingPathTokens.Count - 1);
            }
         }
         else
         {
            resultingPathTokens.Add(pathToken);
         }
      }

      // Get the resulting path
      string resultingPath = String.Join("\\", resultingPathTokens);

      // Check if the path contains only two chars with a colon as the second
      if (resultingPath.Length == 2 && resultingPath[1] == ':')
      {
         // Add a backslash in this case
         resultingPath += "\\";
      }

      return resultingPath;
   }
   return path;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as i understand, in WinRT you rather work with the package's installed location or with "known" folders:

1. Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(fileName)
2. KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFileAsync(fileName)

Comment: .. or with application data folders (ApplicationData.Current) or with the downloads folder (DownloadsFolder) or with some other folders using a FilePicker oder FolderPicker.

Comment: .. or (according to the documentation) with any network folder using an UNC under some conditions (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)

Comment: .. or with any file the user has access to on removable storage devices if the capability "Removable storage" is declared